# Google translate isn't translating the select options

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, google-translate

Okay, i'm implementing the Google Translate using:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
            new google.translate.TranslateElement({
                pageLanguage: 'en',
                autoDisplay:true,
                defaultLanguage: 'en',
                // layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
            }, 'google_translate_element');
        }
    </script>
```

It's working fine, but i'm having this issue of it not translating the select options too.

**I would want the select option to be written in the selected language**, see what i mean here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vUNxWoG6WtRpBgbvU4VV2XFsf-Jiy6p0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've bold the question: I want the select option to be written in the selected language

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete code i used in solving this issues:

```
<style>
#myImageId{
    display: none;
    height: 32px;
    width: 47px;
}

.google-translate {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.goog-logo-link {
    display: none !important;
}

.goog-te-gadget {
    color: transparent !important;
}

.goog-te-banner-frame, .skiptranslates, #goog-gt-tt {
    display: none !important;
}

body {
    top: 0px !important;
}
.goog-te-combo{
    float: right;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    padding:.75rem 1rem;
    font-size:1rem;
    line-height:1.25;
    color:#4E5154;
    background-color:#FFF;
    -webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
    background-clip:padding-box;
    border:1px solid #BABFC7;
    border-radius:.25rem;
    -webkit-transition:border-color .15s ease-in-out,
    -webkit-box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:border-color .15s ease-in-out,
    box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:border-color .15s ease-in-out,
    box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    transition:border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    transition:border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out,-webkit-box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    margin-right:1rem!important
}
</style>


=============================================================
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({ 
        pageLanguage: 'en', 
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, 
        autoDisplay: false 
    }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
=============================================================
<script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
function changeFunc() {
    $('#myImageId').show();
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
    var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;

    var $frame = $('.goog-te-menu-frame:first');
    if (!$frame.length) {
        alert("Error: Could not find Google translate frame.");
        return false;
    }
    $frame.contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item span.text:contains(' + selectedValue + ')').get(0).click();
    var str = selectedValue.substring(0,2).toLowerCase();
    document.getElementById("myImageId").src="https://flagcdn.com/16x12/" + str + ".png"
}
</script>




=============================================================

<div id="google_translate_element" style="display: none"></div>

<div class="d-flex" style="align-items: inherit;">
<img id="myImageId" class="mr-2 img-fluid" alt="Language flags"> 
<select class="form-control mr-3" id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();">

    <option value="German">
        <span>German</span>
    </option>

    <option value="Afrikaans"><span>Afrikaans</span></option>

    <option value="Albanian">
        <span>Albanian</span>
    </option>

    <option value="Amharic">
        <span>Amharic</span>
    </option>

    <option value="Arabic">
        <span>Arabic</span>
    </option>

    <option value="Armenian">
        <span>Armenian</span>
    </option>

    <option value="Azerbaijani">
        <span>Azerbaijani</span>
    </option>

    <option value="Basque">
        <span>Basque</span>
    </option>
    <option value="Belarusian">
        <span>
            Belarusian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Bengali">
        <span>
            Bengali
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Bosnian">
        <span>
            Bosnian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Bulgarian">
        <span>
            Bulgarian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Burmese">
        <span>
            Burmese
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Catalan">
        <span>
            Catalan
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Cebuano">
        <span>
            Cebuano
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Chewa">
        <span>
            Chewa
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Chinese">
        <span>
            Chinese
        </span>
    </option>
    <!-- <option value="Chinese">
        <span>
            Chinese (Simplified)
        </span>
    </option> -->
    <!-- <option value="Chinese">
        <span>
            Chinese (Traditional)
        </span>
    </option> -->
    <option value="sican">
        <span>
            Corsican
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="atian">
        <span>
            Croatian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Czech">
        <span>
            Czech
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Danish">
        <span>
            Danish
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Dutch">
        <span>
            Dutch
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="English"><span>English</span></option>
    <option value="Esperanto">
        <span>
            Esperanto
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Estonian">
        <span>
            Estonian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Filipino">
        <span>
            Filipino (Tagalog)
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Finnish">
        <span>
            Finnish
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="French">
        <span>
            French
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Galician">
        <span>
            Galician
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Georgian">
        <span>
            Georgian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="German">
        <span>
            German
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Greek">
        <span>
            Greek
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Gujarati">
        <span>
            Gujarati
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Haitian">
        <span>
            Haitian Creole
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Hausa">
        <span>
            Hausa
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Hawaiian">
        <span>
            Hawaiian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Hebrew">
        <span>
            Hebrew
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Hindi">
        <span>
            Hindi
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Hmong">
        <span>
            Hmong
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Hungarian">
        <span>
            Hungarian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Icelandic">
        <span>
            Icelandic
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Igbo">
        <span>
            Igbo
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Indonesian">
        <span>
            Indonesian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Irish">
        <span>
            Irish
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Italian">
        <span>
            Italian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Japanese">
        <span>
            Japanese
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Javanese">
        <span>
            Javanese
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Kannada">
        <span>
            Kannada
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Kazakh">
        <span>
            Kazakh
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Khmer">
        <span>
            Khmer
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Kinyarwanda">
        <span>
            Kinyarwanda
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Korean">
        <span>
            Korean
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Kurdish">
        <span>
            Kurdish (Kurmanji)
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Kyrgyz">
        <span>
            Kyrgyz
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Lao">
        <span>
            Lao
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Latin">
        <span>
            Latin
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Latvian">
        <span>
            Latvian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Lithuanian">
        <span>
            Lithuanian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Luxembourgish">
        <span>
            Luxembourgish
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Macedonian">
        <span>
            Macedonian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Malagasy">
        <span>
            Malagasy
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Malay">
        <span>
            Malay
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Malayalam">
        <span>
            Malayalam
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Maltese">
        <span>
            Maltese
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Maori">
        <span>
            Maori
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Marathi">
        <span>
            Marathi
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Mongolian">
        <span>
            Mongolian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Nepali">
        <span>
            Nepali
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Norwegian">
        <span>
            Norwegian (Bokmål)
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Odia">
        <span>
            Odia
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Pashto">
        <span>
            Pashto
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Persian">
        <span>
            Persian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Polish">
        <span>
            Polish
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Portuguese">
        <span>
            Portuguese
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Punjabi">
        <span>
            Punjabi (Gurmukhi)
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Romanian">
        <span>
            Romanian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Russian">
        <span>
            Russian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Samoan">
        <span>
            Samoan
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Scottish">
        <span>
            Scottish Gaelic
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Serbian">
        <span>
            Serbian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Shona">
        <span>
            Shona
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Sindhi">
        <span>
            Sindhi
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Sinhala">
        <span>
            Sinhala
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Slovak">
        <span>
            Slovak
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Slovenian">
        <span>
            Slovenian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Somali">
        <span>
            Somali
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Sotho">
        <span>
            Sotho
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Spanish">
        <span>
            Spanish
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Sundanese">
        <span>
            Sundanese
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Swahili">
        <span>
            Swahili
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Swedish">
        <span>
            Swedish
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Tajik">
        <span>
            Tajik
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Tamil">
        <span>
            Tamil
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Tatar">
        <span>
            Tatar
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="elugu">
        <span>
            Telugu
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Thai">
        <span>
            Thai
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Turkish">
        <span>
            Turkish
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Turkmen">
        <span>
            Turkmen
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Ukrainian">
        <span>
            Ukrainian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Urdu">
        <span>
            Urdu
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Uyghur">
        <span>
            Uyghur
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Uzbek">
        <span>
            Uzbek
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Vietnamese">
        <span>
            Vietnamese
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Welsh">
        <span>
            Welsh
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="West">
        <span>
            West Frisian
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Xhosa">
        <span>
            Xhosa
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Yiddish">
        <span>
            Yiddish
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Yoruba">
        <span>
            Yoruba
        </span>
    </option>
    <option value="Zulu">
        <span>
            Zulu
        </span>
    </option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Please if you have any other option better than this; please let me know.

Comment: I worked in it and got this: https://github.com/cletuskingdom/google-translate-with